# How do I turn on powered rails?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am building a roller coaster. How do I make powered rails work? I am having trouble riding my roller coaster. I have been annoyed working on it for a while and then not being able to use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powered rails need to be powered to work. Use a redstone signal to power them. you can use a redstone block next to, or beneath the powered rail, or use a redstone torch next to the rail.

Another method is to put a detector rail in front of a powerd rail. This will send a redstone signal into the powerd rail.

A lot of this stuff can be found on the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail)

Answer (score 1):

You can activate powered rails by either powering them with redstone, or using detector rails.

Redstone torches are the easiest way to go, and will power the rail if they are adjacent to the powered rail, or underneath the block the rail is sitting on.

Detector rails can be placed in front of powered rails to power them, but only when a minecart rides over the detector rail.

Comment: Technically, using detector rails is just another way to power them with redstone

Answer (score -1):

to turn you need to put one normal rail track the powered one. itll cause it to curve